# Why my code is behaving like this?

Tags: c, string, pointers

This is my first question here so i apologize if its not a useful question.

I have this project of a simulator where the user calls the program via command line with some parameters. Like, `MYPROG [options] filename`.

I need to make sure the filename is valid, where it is (directory) and get the name for further use.

Here is part of the code:

```
char* ExtrairNome(char* alvo){
    char* teste = alvo;
    char* nome = NULL;
    int barras = 0;

    while(strcmp(teste, "") != 0){ //look for "/"
        if (teste[0] == '/') barras++;
        teste++;
    }

    teste = alvo;
    if (barras > 0){
        while(barras > 0){ //remove everything leaving the "filename.ias"
            if (teste[0] == '/') barras--;
            teste++;
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    char aux[strlen(teste) - 4];
    while (strcmp(teste, ".ias")){ //remove the ".ias"
        aux[i] = teste[0];
        teste++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("random %d\n", barras); //this line fixes the bug!!
    aux[i] = '\0';
    nome = aux;
    return nome;
}
```

This function receives the string with the full filename and should return only the name, without extention or path. But it only works when i printf some variable before returning. If i remove that line the function returns nothing. 
I think it has something to do with scope but i don't know for sure. How can i fix this?

Comment: You are in fact returning a local variable by pointer. That will lead to undefined behavior. Make the function accept a caller-allocated char buffer and write to that instead.

Comment: For testing blank string, just `while (teste[0])` is enough, no need to call `strcmp(teste, "") != 0` which is much slower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nome is a pointer, so you can return the address of the solution.
Problem is aux, which is in the stack, and once you return, it doesn't exist anymore, so behaviour is unknown. You have two choices, declaring "aux" in a higher scope and pass it to your function, and passing a pointer to the buffer solution or allocate in the function(using malloc) and then free(when its not necessary).

i mean:

```
char name[100];
ExtrairNome(alvo, name);//pass a pointer to the function

void ExtrairNome(char * alvo, char * aux)
{
     ...;//everything is the same
     //except you don't create aux here, you use the one you created in your main function
}
```

or

```
char * ExtrairNome(char * alvo, char * aux)
{
     ...;//everything is the same
     char * aux = (char*)malloc((strlen(teste)-4 )* sizeof(char));
     ...;//everything the same
}
//remember to free() when you are done using it
```

Comment: Another solution would be to declare aux as `static`, then it would still exist outside of the function. (I'd generally consider that to be poor program design, but it's an option nevertheless.)

Comment: True, also you could declare it as global, but still, not a good practice, static has another reason to be there.

Comment: I'll try using `malloc` and change the return type to void. @karadoc I can't use static as the size is variable.

Comment: I had a SegFault with the second solution but the first one works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Probably writing more chars than the allocated ones.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to a local automatic (stack) variable - aux. That does not exist after the function returns. This is undefined behavior. The fact that it 'works' when you print a variable is one possibility for undefined behavior.